# Looking for a good jQuery/JavaScript validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any suggestions for a good/simple clientside validation plugin or tutorial?

- Would like to do real time validation for each field using blur.
- Would like many validation schemes to be built in (i.e. date correct, phone numbers, etc) but allow ajax calls as needed (existing username, valid zipcode, etc.
- Needs to check for required fields upon submit.
- Want ability to custom style error messages next to each field.
- Might be nice to allow same plugin to deal with displaying final serverside validation errors when data is eventually posted to be saved.
- Maybe nice to show suggestion text upon focus.

Or is it just as easy to make from scratch?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the post, and I read it.  Yes, whats better/worse without giving specific requirements is useless.  Thought I gave specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery.validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) is the obvious candidate.

Comment: I was looking at this one, but didn't know if it was any good.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user1032531 it basically does everything you asked for except the last two, which would probably be better done with other means.

Comment: The documentation looks good, however, a getting started tutorial might make the learning curve more fun.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1032531 [sure](http://goo.gl/9v5TJ)

Comment: Nice answer Scott!  I actually did just that before commenting, but didn't find anything that wowed me.  I will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great validation plugin at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. It's very customizable and has good documentation for basic usage, although you might have to go searching for instructions on how to do more complex validation.